# Concatenating on index and key in pandas

Tags: join, pandas, concatenation

I'm not sure that I'm using the terms correctly as I am quite new to pandas and python. However, I have two dataframes that I would like to join into one. They can be matched on the index column and an other key column (sample). 'sample' ranges from 001 to 100 and the index from 1 to 729 for each sample.

df1

```
    sample  x1  x2  x3  x4
id                  
1   068 421.67  0.34    0.71    0.928
2   068 28.77   0.07    0.81    0.952
3   068 4.01    0.36    0.70    0.925
4   068 41.07   0.32    0.70    0.924
```

df2

```
    q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  sample
id                                                                                  
1   a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c2  068
2   a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c4  068
3   a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c5  068
4   a1  a2  r1  r2  c3  c2  068
```

Result

```
    sample x1       x2      x3      x4     q1   q2  q3  q4  q5  q6  
id                  
1   068   41.967    0.34    0.71    0.928  a1   a2  r1  r2  c1  c2  
2   068   28.77     0.07    0.81    0.952  a1   a2  r1  r2  c1  c4  
3   068   4.01      0.36    0.70    0.925  a1   a2  r1  r2  c1  c5  
4   068   41.07     0.32    0.70    0.924  a1   a2  r1  r2  c3  c2
```

Comment: What if they have same index but different sample or different index but same sample? How do you want to do it then? Also, your example will end with two columns with the same name. In this one, the values are the same, but after the joining, you may end up with different values based on how you will join them. And it isn't something you want :)

Comment: @Tasos Seems I accedentily put two columns in and different values. of course i want it to be the same. For each sample there are 729 rows the index (id) corresponding to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) for that 2 dataframes on `id` and `sample` column. Then rename columns if you want them to be q1, q2 ...:

```
In [33]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'sample'])
Out[33]:
   id  sample      x1    x2    x3     x4  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c2
0   1      68  421.67  0.34  0.71  0.928  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c2
1   2      68   28.77  0.07  0.81  0.952  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c4
2   3      68    4.01  0.36  0.70  0.925  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c5
3   4      68   41.07  0.32  0.70  0.924  a1  a2  r1  r2  c3  c2
```

If you want to change column names:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'sample'])
df3.columns = df3.columns[:-6].tolist() + ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6']

In [50]: df3
Out[50]:
   id  sample      x1    x2    x3     x4  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6
0   1      68  421.67  0.34  0.71  0.928  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c2
1   2      68   28.77  0.07  0.81  0.952  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c4
2   3      68    4.01  0.36  0.70  0.925  a1  a2  r1  r2  c1  c5
3   4      68   41.07  0.32  0.70  0.924  a1  a2  r1  r2  c3  c2
```

**EDIT**

You could create sequence for column names (if you have them a lot) as:

```
In [87]: ['q' + str(num) for num in range(1,7)]
Out[87]: ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6']
```